# How to call exit from a script loaded via rb_load_protect without a segfault

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I want to quit the application with success from Ruby 2.3.3 (Win32). I get a segfault when I try to exit the program from that script.

I tried the following:

```
# script.rb
loop do
    # do something
    exit 0 if foo()
    break if bar()
end
```

`foo` and `bar` are just returning `Qtrue` or `Qfalse`.

I load the script with:

```
ruby_init();

int ruby_state = 0;
VALUE script = rb_str_new_cstr("./script.rb");
rb_load_protect(script, 0, &ruby_state);

ruby_cleanup(ruby_state);
```

and it produces a segfault. I also tried to put `ruby_cleanup` in a function called from Ruby, but it produces the same segfault.

How can I stop the Ruby VM, or at least stop the current script?

Comment: Try `exit!`. It ignores callbacks an so on.

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Comment: Then please mark it as resolved. I added the answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `exit!`. It ignores callbacks an so on.